# How to create a docker compose file to support multiple databases

Tags: docker, docker-compose

What I want to achieve:

I want a docker-compose file to spin up

1. one application from .jar file
2. one DB server running 2 databases under two users

I have the .jar set up and it works fine, but I can't get it to work with 2 databases.

With docker-compose:

```
version: "3.2"
services:
  db:
      container_name: postgresserver
      image: mdillon/postgis
      ports:
          - "54322:5432"
      environment:
          POSTGRES_DB: "postgres"
          POSTGRES_USER: "postgres"
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "postgres"

  db2:
      extends: db
      container_name: postgresserver2
      environment:
          POSTGRES_DB: "postgres2"
          POSTGRES_USER: "postgres2"
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "postgres2"
```

Currently I get

```
ERROR: The Compose file '.\docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
Unsupported config option for services.db2: 'extends'
```

Any working samples with postgre and postgis? (did not find any from SO or google).

Also regular docker build/run setup would solve my problem, but I could not get that working either.

Comment: In your compose file you wouldn't get one server with two databases, you would get two servers with a database each. Which is probably the better solution anyway. If you only want one server, then run one database and create an additional DB user and add the additional schema. Not sure there is any reason to run two db instances on the exact same server.

Answer (score 0):

`extends:` is only supported up to V2.1 of the compose file (see [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/#extending-services)), and your file is tagged as V3.2, so that's why you get that error.

If you're not going to use Docker Swarm in your project (which is basically a multi node orchestration service) you could just change the version of the file to 2.1, or re-define it so it doesn't use `extends:`